# Converting: `system.net.http.httpresponemessage` to `system.io.stream` in C#

Tags: c#

**My CurrentCode:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
})
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl));

    // convert stream to string
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respons);

    var myItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelClassObject>(response);

    return myItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReadAsStreamAsync` on the content of the response

```
using(var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl))) {
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    //...
}
```

If you want to parse JOSN directly from the response, then

```
using(var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl))) {
    var myItems = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelClassObject>();
    return myItems;
}
```